# Go back from React Native to Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to get back from RN to Android. This [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler) shows an example using `BackHandler` event. The presented approach will work well for screens that are shown in a StackNavigator. However, the last Android Screen is not in StackNavigator. How could I go back to the last Android Screen that triggered RN application?

When implementing the basic `BackHandler`, I can see in the logs `You clicked on YES!`, but exiting the app somehow is not executed `BackHandler.exitApp()`.

I guess to go from RN to Android is not straighforward as just including the following code because the Android application that called RN application is not part of the react-navigation, so there is no link and this is why even the RN application is not going away.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, BackHandler, Alert } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => null,
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
      ]);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Click Back button!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

export default App;
```

However, I am wondering if I am missing some configuration in Android? The activity calling RN application is the following:

```
package com.reactnative;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.reactnative.BuildConfig;

public class MyFirstReactActivity extends ReactActivity  implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();

        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(new HermesExecutorFactory())
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(packages)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
        
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "ReactNativeProject", initialProperties);

        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this);
        }
        if (mReactRootView != null) {
            mReactRootView.unmountReactApplication();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted
                Log.d("PERMISSION", "Permission not granted!!");
            }
        }
        mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ReactNativeProject";
    }
}
```

How do you go back to last Android Screen from React Native?

Thanks a lot for any comment, advise.

Comment: Wondering if you would not need to trigger React Native inside a fragment? https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-android-fragment and in this case back button would work